# Import React component from Git submodule repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, git-submodules

I have a parent repository developed with React, and I have a child Sub Module inside of it(which is developed by react too):

The project folder structure is something like below:

```
parent 
  /.git
  /nodemodule
  /src
  /subModules/childProject
     /.git
     /src
       /js
         /x.jsx //  i want this file from parent project
     /...
  /...
```

I want to access and use the `x.jsx` component from parent project. I imported it like blow in my parent project:

```
import X from '../subModules/childProject/src/js/x.jsx'
```

but it gives me `unexpected token`!

```
   7 |   return (
>  8 |     <article className="center">
     |     ^
   9 |       this is test global component with in child Project
  10 |     </article>
  11 |   )
```

it looks like that it cannot transform it because I wrote just a test function in old JavaScript way like:

```
export default function test(x) {
  return x * 2
}
```

It imported without any error and works but when I wrote function in arrow style like below:

```
export default function test(x) => x * 2
```

it does not work. It seems like it's just a runtime error of transpiling modules, how can I transpile and import react components from child submodule in to parent repository?

Comment: We need more information, did you use `create-react-app`? what version are you using? Seems to be that you just need a .babelrc file

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that Babel does not know that there is a submodule project in the root of the project, just by changing my `.babelrc` file to `babel.config.js` and configuring it by `babelrcRoots` I would be able to **solve** the issue:

Now my `babel.config.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "babelrcRoots": [ "./", "./subModules/someFolder" ]
}
```

Now I can import any react component and JS modules from sub-repository in side my parent project and it works correctly.

Comment: I've tried including the submodules folder to `babelrcroots` in my craco.config. The jsx doesn't get transformed although other syntax like null point coalescence expressions do.